# Does a 1-sample KS test compare raw data or a fitted model with a given distribution?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

my question is: For a 1-sample K-S test should I be comparing my raw data to a given distribution (in this case, gamma) or comparing a fitted model to a given distribution?

I am using scipy

Comment: In R, the procedure `ks.test` compares a sample from a continuous distribution with a known distribution (parameters specified). If you have to estimate parameters you need a procedure that adjusts the distribution of the test statistic for that estimation.

Answer (score 0):

One sample KS test compares a raw data set to a given (fully specified) distribution. To be precise it compares the [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) to the theoretical.

Comment: So to be clear, I should run the KS test against my raw data and a fully specified distribution

Comment: Yes, empirical cdf will be constructed from raw data then compared to theoretical